# Select some entities from row in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have in my grid sometimes few columns, I hide some that only two are visible. I want to select rows only with these two entities(visible) and pass them to array. In this example Date and Result. Is there specific method to do this? Because when I use 
`vm.chartData.push($scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows())` in chartData array I have got all entities. 
This is my controller code.

```
(function () { "use strict";

angular.module("app")
.controller("grid", grid);

function grid($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.chartData = [];

    $scope.gridOptions =
    {
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'Trial', field: 'Trial' },
          { name: 'Date', field: 'Date', type: "date", cellFilter: "date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'" },
          { name: 'Result', field: 'Result'}
        ],
        data: [
            //example of row entities
            { 
                "Trial": "Weight",
                "Date": "2015-02-03T05:49:54.850Z",
                "Result": 60 
            }
        ]
    };
    $scope.pushAll = function () {
        //this line returns all three entities
        vm.chartData.push($scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows());

    };
    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) { 
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    };

}
```

Comment: Would you be able to paste in a little more of your code? It would be easier to understand the problem with your grid config, where you load the data etc.